# How to visualize in Rviz a programmed nxt robot with ROS (nxt-pthon)?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I run the nxt-robot with ros (nxt-python), I can't visualize it in Rviz... Is it possible???
please help me....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50131/how-to-visualize-in-rviz-a-programmed-nxt-robot-with-ros-(nxt-pthon)?/) by [mutreras](https://answers.ros.org/users/3761/mutreras/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mutreras](https://answers.ros.org/users/3761/mutreras/) on 2012-12-11**:
thanks.. but I made it... its works ok... thats no the problem.... the problem is when the robot runs with a programmed nxt-python ... is this case rviz cant visualize the programmed motion sequence...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For visualization in rviz, you first need to create a robot description file. Have a look at [these tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials). After you have the URDF file, you need to make sure that you are getting your robot's joint states and run the robot state publisher node. One of the tutorials I mentioned shows how.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mutreras](https://answers.ros.org/users/3761/mutreras/) on 2013-05-07**:
I have other problem... i nedd a combined publisher and subscriber node in python... How can I do it??